# How to verify that a replace has occured with Python re.subn

Tags: python, replace

I couldn't find a similar question on this, so feel free to direct me elsewhere.

I am trying to verify that a string has been replaced. I was previously using the .replace() function but that doesnt return anything to tell me it has been replaced. I was directed to the re.subn method but I'm not quite sure how it works.

This is what i have so far. I'm trying to read the file line by line, when it finds the string to replace, it replaces it, and then increase the count by 1.

```
i= 1
newfile=open(fileOutput,'w', encoding="utf8")
for line in open("tempFile.txt", encoding="utf8"):
    line, numReplacements=re.subn("text to find", "replacementText")
    newfile.write(line)  
    if numReplacements < 0:
         i+=1
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the principale argument : the line on which apply the replacement

```
line, numReplacements = re.subn("text to find", "replacementText", line)
```

But you are right about what it returns : `a 2-tuple containing (new_string, number)`

> - `new_string` is the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
>   non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in the source
>   string by the replacement repl.
> - `number` is the number of substitutions that were made.

---

### Fix

But then you need to change 2 things

- the order of the condition, you want to add if the number of replacement is positive
- to be generic, you may have more then one replacement, so use that value to sum up with the previous

```
if numReplacements > 0:
     i += numReplacements
```

---

### Better

- you can remove the the `if`, as sum with `0` is not really a problem
- you may use the `with` clause to open the file, so it closes by itself at the end, for both file

```
i = 0
with open(fileOutput, 'w', encoding="utf8") as outfile, \
        open("tempFile.txt", encoding="utf8") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line, numReplacements = re.subn("text to find", "replacementText", line)
        outfile.write(line)
        i += numReplacements
```

Comment: brilliant thanks. I'd missed that third argument. 

I also had my sign the wrong way round too!  thanks!